# Avoid duplicate entries in List<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I check that List< SelectListItem> doesn't contain or insert any duplicates in Mvc3. I have tried with !Contains

Thanks

Comment: Did one of the answers helped you? If yes, can you accept one as the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Some Text", Value = "Some Value" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other Text", Value = "Other Value" });

var selectListItem = new SelectListItem { Text = "Some Text", Value = "Some Value" };
if(!list.Any(l => l.Value == selectListItem.Value)
{
    list.Add(selectListItem);
}
```

.Contains() compares if the object reference, not the Value property

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();

var selectListItem = new SelectListItem { Text = "Some Text", Value = "Some Value" };
if(list.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Value != selectListItem.Value) == null)
{
    list.Add(selectListItem);
}
```

Comment: I have used List<SelectListItem> list=new List<SelectListItem>(); Its not working

Comment: if(list.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Value != selectListItem.Value) == null) not correct it has to be if(list.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Value == selectListItem.Value) == null)